# How to develop cross platform shared libraries and an API?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, shared

I want to write an shared library for Linux and Windows. My code must cross-compile on that operating systems. What is the **best way** to achieve this ? (compilers to be used are GCC on Linux and mingw on windows)

Comment: Write C code that conforms to the standard and doesn't depend on OS-specific APIs.

Comment: That's highly depends on what your program should do. `int main(void) { printf("hello, world!"); return 0; }` is perfectly portable, but doesn't do anything useful. From the other hand, there're a lot of cool APIs which are available only on a particular platform (say Cocoa in MacOSX or DirectX in Windows). So first you have to decide what area your portable application would target, to whom you wish to write it and then choose appropriate instruments.